# xpages: images and attachments links with copyallitems in LotusScript

Tags: xpages

In my application, we create a draft document out the published one, so we can work on the draft and publish when we are ready.

The publication is done through LotusScript, as the same code is used for a scheduled agent that publishes on specific dates.

Since we need to keep the UNID of the original document (for existing doc links in same and other apps), we do a little dance when we publish, so that the content of the draft goes into the published document, then saved.  The copy of the draft content to the published content is done this way:

```
Call draftDoc.copyAllItems(publishedDoc, True)
```

Unfortunately, the images and attachments links are built using the draft's UNID, and of course, these don't work once we copied all items to a different document (the published document).

I am clueless on this one...  We really need to keep the same UNID on the published doc, for backward compatibility, and we can't ahve the users create their images and links with the published's UNID as some of the files might not already be in the published document, as no preview would be possible then.

Any thoughts, ideas, tips, tricks, other way of doing this are welcomed  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few steps should you get where you need to be:

- change the storage format of your RichText field to Mime
- copy all items
- retrieve the RT content as Mime. Look for the text/HTML part
- replace the UNID string in there with the correct one

If you write it in Java. JTagSoup makes dealing with HTML and attributes quite easy. You technically only need src and href

Comment: Stephan (got it right did this time :P),  I thought about a similar procedure last night, but I was thinking of doing it in JavaScript, on the onLoad event of the document.  I can't recall why we didn't go with the rt field storiage as MIME, but if I recall correctly the summary was exceeding 32K.due to heavy usage of  Dojo sections in the web editor and they are not showing up in edit mode.  Users are doing a lot of edits.  I think that this is what was causing the MIME tracking field to bust.

I'll have a look at what you suggested, and may wery well convert that Lotuscript agent to Java.
:D

Comment: MIME content is not bound by a 32k limit. What issue are you facing there?

Comment: Strange. RichText isn't a summary field. Ask a new question and add the code

Comment: I don't think the summary error has to do with it, but since the MIME tracking field gets big, we get that error quite often.  we need to check which fields are flagged as summary first...